# How to fix 'client_id is missing or too long' while trying to login from an asp.net core 2.2 web app

Tags: authorization, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm setting up my identity server to get access from a temporary port forwarded ip. The login works perfectly when I run everything localy but when I start using my public IP, it says that my client_id is missing or too long.

First I got an error that it couldnt access a local http request. This was because of the endpoints not using the right redirect URI's. I changed this by changing the public origin of the identityserver.

After that I could reach my login page and try to login to get an error

Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request
Invalid client_id

I checked the client id, but it's the right one.
In the console I get

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      client_id is missing or too long
{
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "Raw": {
          "ReturnUrl": "/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=pokemon_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbackendpokemonsite.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token%20code&scope=openid%20profile%20pokemon%20role%20offline_access%20email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636932445888919509.YTM5OTBlNDMtNWJkNC00MTJiLWI3YjAtNTIzMzY0ZmNkOGEyNzNlMjVhZjQtZGJhNC00MDk2LWIxYjItY2MwNWFmYTczNmU0&state=CfDJ8IxZ9MXLdlhLon2k58KSiTd3i19Dt1TM93X6-L-_SyUK_xpG5zn90n4y9RtMGlieCkdOPPnAg2VXrLoy1EXTZgGlLmsd7EIqORzq37XbF6Zj23rr7_shXOQcLY87Dywalv4VrRj6HKqUnNFGUE8cCKSXc6uiH0LDBTDPqAuU2QWWRJf-a07TAZw2YdbvanEbueXDKAL9ty57_O2pY1rS5_7ViiVVu_GP3ct8ytW6wY8_BBArqQZW7BspbQV5YzDfseVcSnh1dIRPXZTSvUyHWMvBIQTYb_xhctLoOpdzQC41XMCjP9lpkTBm2Vwv-izxlDWbT58DnVwNKnYTYUn0nhA",
          "Username": "username",
          "Password": "password",
          "button": "login",
          "__RequestVerificationToken": "CfDJ8N6qinc1TjFHrjbGhp-Exm0qSNXoKKJC77ipFBHfZWz2ukCowIEjgzRUy3ZRex2SEVLByyYCDoOfjxR-JUfdBj6IDUZAI5EHcFklOPLssWob-yJrrCio3VyrClZnlYkHSif3-yDvU0w-2GDs6S2lIKM",
          "RememberLogin": "false"
        }
      }
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Request validation failed
```

My onconfigure services from my identity server where I change my endpoint locations to my public IP:

```cs
  services.AddIdentityServer(options=> options.PublicOrigin= "http://public-endpoint")
.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Configuration/pokemon.pfx","secretpassword"))                .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options => options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), dboptions => dboptions.MigrationsAssembly(assembly)))
                .AddOperationalStore(options => options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), dboptions => dboptions.MigrationsAssembly(assembly)))
                .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```

This is my onconfigure for my web project:

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            services.AddAuthentication(options=> {

                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";

            }).AddCookie("Cookies").AddOpenIdConnect("oidc",openid=> {
                openid.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                openid.AuthenticationMethod = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost;
                openid.Authority = "http://public-endpoint/";
                openid.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                openid.ClaimActions.Add(new RoleClaimAction());
                openid.ClientId = "pokemon_code";
                openid.ClientSecret = "secret";
                openid.ResponseType = "id_token code";
                openid.Scope.Add("pokemon");
                openid.Scope.Add("role");
                openid.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                openid.Scope.Add("email");
                openid.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "role",
                    NameClaimType="role"
                };
                openid.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                openid.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

I expect the website to login ask for permission to use the account details. but now I get the error:
"Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request 
Invalid client_id".
I'm pretty new to identity server so did i miss something?

Comment: `openid.ClientId = "pokemon_code";` doesnt exist or isnt configured for openid flows in your configuration database is the most common. Also make sure to request `openid` scope `openid.Scope.Add("openid");`

Comment: the clientid is right, it uses the same databaseconnection as when i run it offline. I don't know if I had to change much to access it with my public. I changed the redirect uri. but that works great. Also added the `openid.Scope.Add("openid);`not seeing much difference.

Comment: In my experience, when a client or scope are invalid then the login page isn't shown at all. So that's not where the problem is. Seems more an encoding problem, causing a problem decoding the body. You can try removing the `openid.AuthenticationMethod` line, or check the encoding of the form.

Comment: I removed `openid.AuthenticationMethod` but it's still the same. But how can the form is still the quickstart template from IdentityServer and works good locally. So the encoding shouldn't be different right?

Comment: seems to be a redirection issue. after submitting the login form you have to go to [HttpPost]login action in account controller, but you seem to repeatably jump to authorize endpoint. why? check that your [AllowAnonymous] is in place on the controller. the complete (debug level) idsrv log could be useful to distinguish the problem

Comment: to check that your IdSrv is up, try http://public-endpoint/grants it should ask your creds before displaying the page

Comment: @d_f Its going to grants and shows the login form but it isnt going to the login action. the post goes to the grant itself with a result of a 404. however i port forwarded to my laptop and it worked like a charm. so i'll try to run it on another device now to see if it works there and try to figure out what's the problem

Comment: so the problem is inside your idsrv host app and not related to your client' configuration. that's already something at least. check the routing, port forwarding etc and that's it.